# Python absl logging without timestamp module name

Tags: python, logging, abseil, absl-py

I wanted to know if its possible to log only the msg string in absl python without timestamp and module name.
Example

```
I0108 23:40:57.153055 140614090106688 extractor.py:79] processing file: dfcsdf
I0108 23:40:57.162382 140614090106688 extractor.py:72] ['/topic/fdfgd', dfgsdf']
I0108 23:40:57.162861 140614090106688 extractor.py:79] processing file: f456546fd
I0108 23:40:57.171764 140614090106688 extractor.py:72] ['/topic/1', '/topic/2', '/topic/3']
```

is there a configuration to log just message as below

```
processing file: dfcsdf
['/topic/fdfgd', dfgsdf']
processing file: f456546fd
['/topic/1', '/topic/2', '/topic/3']
```

I know I can replace the logging with print for console or write custom logger, I wanted to know if its possible in absl logging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Setting formatter to `None`

You can set the formatter to `None`. It may seem a bit tricky since it's not well documented (I had to read the [source code](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-py/blob/06edd9c20592cec39178b94240b5e86f32e19768/absl/logging/__init__.py) to make sure this is is correct), but the following works:

```
from absl import app
from absl import logging


def main(argv):
    logging.get_absl_handler().use_absl_log_file('log', "./FolderName")

    logging.get_absl_handler().setFormatter(None)

    logging.info('Info log')
    logging.warning('Warning log')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(main)
```

My log file looks like this after setting formatter to `None`:

> Info log
>
> Warning log

### Custom formatter

That being said, implementing a custom formatter is not hard and I think is more elegant, plus it allows you to customize your output. You simply need to override the `format` function:

```
from absl import app
from absl import logging
from absl.logging import PythonFormatter

class CustomPythonFormatter(PythonFormatter):
    def format(self, record):
        return super(PythonFormatter, self).format(record)

def main(argv):
    logging.get_absl_handler().use_absl_log_file('log', "./Folder")

    logging.get_absl_handler().setFormatter(CustomPythonFormatter())

    logging.info('Info log')
    logging.warning('Warning log')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(main)
```

This gives me the same result as before:

> Info log
>
> Warning log